# HornetQ: which versions can be considered stable?

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

I've read the HornetQ FAQ, but I can't find anything related.
I'm using HornetQ 2.2.5, it contains a bug (yeah, just one ;). According to this post https://community.jboss.org/message/624958?tstart=2 it's been fixed from 2.2.7.Final onward.
On the main download page, http://www.jboss.org/hornetq/downloads the latest version available is 2.2.5.Final. I'm not scared of compiling a newer version myself, but can I consider it stable?
I'd say yes since it's a minor release update, but I'd like some other opinions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer uses the **2.3.X branch** as an example. Let's skip looking at their Downloads page, and go straight to the artifacts:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hornetq/hornetq-pom

You can see that 2.3.X went through Alpha, Beta and CR stages, to finally reach 2.3.0.Final, the Community release. This is what most people in the open source world would end up using, and what you will find available for easy download.

It's also the last version the non-paying customers are intended to use (in the typical JBoss release cycle - see e.g. the [JBoss AS/EAP FAQ](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/faq)). Now, from a commerical perspective, 2.3.0.Final would be considered Alpha again. An analogy from the JBoss AS/EAP FAQ which probably applies here too: "The first EAP stage Alpha is of equivalent, or better, quality to a community Final release [...] we don't recommend using it in production" (probably an overly harsh judgement, but anyway.)

After 2.3.0.Final, they fix more bugs (2.3.1.Final, 2.3.2.Final, ...) until they get to a commercial production release (which they bundle into their other commercial products). So, you should be using the latest **.Final** that you can for production (for the 2.3.X branch, it was **2.3.13.Final**).

**Do you have to pay for 2.3.13.Final?** From what I can tell, you don't. (HornetQ is also not available commercially AFAICT, except when bundled into other products.)

**How do you get 2.3.13.Final?** You probably won't find a nicely packaged RPM or even zip file. Instead, you will need to get the JARs from public Maven repos (or build from source).

Do you need a postgrad degree in JBoss Versioning and Product Naming to use their products? Perhaps :) - I don't have one, so apologies in advance if I have failed to comprehend the enormous complexity of the beast. But I do wish the HornetQ developers would make it easy to get a stable release of their product, and know that this is what one is using. It's a good product (perhaps the most fully featured of the lot), with an excellent manual, but a snap judgement of the download page and FAQ may make some people look at competing projects instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some more research, I can say yes, it is stable.
In particular, JBoss EAP 5.1.2 package includes HornetQ version 2.2.10.GA.
I wonder why there is no direct link on the HornetQ download page.